# Unable to connect to MySQL Server from node.js, but works from JetBrains Datagrip

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a server where docker containers are running.

1. Node.js docker
2. MySQL docker

They are able to communicate each other without any problem.

To connect to MySQL database from outside the server, I use a Jetbrain's Datagrip which works fine.

What I was able to do before installed an "nginx server", I could connect to a remote MYSQL server from my node.js app running on my local pc.

Now it doesn't allow me to connect directly to db server from local machine anymore, here is the error I get:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/home/user/code/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:205:17)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}
```

How could I find out what is causing this issue ? Any idea?